# How can I disable anti-aliasing for a custom trackImage for UIProgressView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, progress-bar, pixel, antialiasing

I have an outlet called xpBar, which is a UIProgressView. I need to disable anti-aliasing for the custom track and progress images, but the only layer I can find in there does not affect the track and progress images, apparently.

```
self.xpBar.trackImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar_grey.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 4, 4, 4)];
self.xpBar.layer.magnificationFilter = kCAFilterNearest; // Does nothing :(
```

Do I really need to subclass UIProgressView to do this, and if so, how would I get rid of anti-aliasing that way?

Comment: That does nothing to the antialiasing unless your layer is scaled.

Comment: Have you checked the the image is not miss-aligned?

Comment: My track and progress images are very small and should be stretched without antialiasing... The progressview is placed on x.0 coordinates and has x.0 width and height, if that is what you are asking?